# I can't use the wrap widget side by side

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

*Create 20 container widgets side by side using the «wrap» widget
*Leave a 3-pixel space between them horizontally.
*Place the containers in the middle of the screen and type 1-2-3-4-5 in them.

I need to design a container widget in line with the above prompts, but when I ran the code I wrote, I saw that the containers are not side by side? What am I doing wrong?

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
void main()
{runApp(
    MaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    home:Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text(
    "Containers in wraps",
    style: TextStyle(color:Colors.greenAccent.shade400),
  ),
  backgroundColor: Colors.black,
  ),
  body: Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
  child: Wrap(
    alignment: WrapAlignment.center,
  spacing:3.0,
    runAlignment: WrapAlignment.center,
  runSpacing:3.0,
  children: [
  Expanded(
  child: Container(

  color: Colors.grey,
  child: Center(
  child: Text(
  "1",
  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red,fontSize: 20),
  ),
  ),
  ),),
  SizedBox(width:10,),
  Expanded(
  child: Container(
  color: Colors.lightGreen,
child: Center(
child: Text(
"2",
style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red,fontSize: 20),
),
),
),),
SizedBox(width:10,),
    Expanded(
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.lightGreen,
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            "3",
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red,fontSize: 20),
          ),
        ),
      ),),
    SizedBox(width:10,),
    Expanded(
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.lightGreen,
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            "4",
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red,fontSize: 20),
          ),
        ),
      ),),
    SizedBox(width:10,),
Expanded(
child: Container(

color: Colors.blue,
child: Center(
child: Text(
"5",
style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red,fontSize: 20),
),
),
),),
],
),
),
  ),
    ),
);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `Expanded` use `UnconstraindedBox`. Following code should help:

```
void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(
            "Containers in wraps",
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.greenAccent.shade400),
          ),
          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        ),
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
          child: Wrap(
            alignment: WrapAlignment.center,
            spacing: 3.0,
            runAlignment: WrapAlignment.center,
            runSpacing: 3.0,
            children: [
              UnconstrainedBox(
                child: Container(
                  constraints: const BoxConstraints.tightFor(),
                  color: Colors.grey,
                  child: const Center(
                    child: Text(
                      "1",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontSize: 20),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                width: 10,
              ),
              UnconstrainedBox(
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.lightGreen,
                  constraints: const BoxConstraints.tightFor(),
                  child: const Center(
                    child: Text(
                      "2",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontSize: 20),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                width: 10,
              ),
              UnconstrainedBox(
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.lightGreen,
                  constraints: const BoxConstraints.tightFor(),
                  child: const Center(
                    child: Text(
                      "3",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontSize: 20),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                width: 10,
              ),
              UnconstrainedBox(
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.lightGreen,
                  constraints: const BoxConstraints.tightFor(),
                  child: const Center(
                    child: Text(
                      "4",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontSize: 20),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                width: 10,
              ),
              UnconstrainedBox(
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  constraints: const BoxConstraints.tightFor(),
                  child: const Center(
                    child: Text(
                      "5",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontSize: 20),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Using `Expanded` inside `Wrap` causes error while running your app.